# Why am I getting an exponential number of calls into my sub-function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda, exponential

I have a problem with the following Haskell function:

```
evalPol :: Float
        -> Float
        -> Integer
        -> Integer
        -> (s -> a -> [(s, [(Float, Float)])])
        -> (s -> a)
        -> [s]
        -> [((s -> Float), Float)]
        -> [((s -> Float), Float)]
evalPol eps gamma maxIter nIter gen pol ss vofss =
  if nIter >= maxIter || delta < eps
    then reverse ((vofs', delta) : vofss)
    else evalPol eps gamma maxIter (nIter + 1) gen pol ss ((vofs', delta) : vofss)
 where delta   = maximum [abs (vofs s - vofs' s) | s <- ss]
       vofs' s = actVal gamma gen vofs s (pol s)
       vofs    = (fst . P.head) vofss
```

If I call this function with `maxIter = 1` and run with profiling then I see function entry counts, which make sense to me:

```
evalPol..............2
  evalPol.delta......1
    evalPol.vofs'..441
```

The function entry count numbers, above, make sense to me, as follows:

1. `evalPol` is entered twice:

   1. once, when called from outside, and
   2. once, recursively. (Only one recursive call is allowed, due to: `maxIter = 1`.)
2. `evalPol.delta` is called only once, because when `evalPol` is called the second time (recursively) the test: `nIter >= maxIter` succeeds, and there is no need to evaluate `delta`.
3. It makes sense that I get 441 entries into `evalPol.vofs'`, because I'm mapping that function over the list, `ss`, and there are 441 items in that list.

Now, if I make only one change: calling `evalPol` with `maxIter = 2`, I find that my program doesn't terminate in a reasonable amount of time.
Allowing it to run for several hours before interupting it, I get the following instead:

```
evalPol................2
  evalPol.delta........2
    evalPol.vofs'..60366
```

The change in the number of entries to `evalPol.delta` from 1 to 2 (See #2, above.) makes sense to me, since I've set `maxIter = 2`.
However, I was *not* expecting such a blow up in the number of entries into `evalPol.vofs'`.
(I was expecting to see 882 entries, 441 for each allowed recursion.)
It looks like the number of entries into `evalPol.vofs'` is *exponential* in `maxIter`.
(I don't know this, since I didn't let the program finish.)

If I "unroll" this 2 recursion case, looking for an exponential dependency upon `maxIter`, I get:

```
-- This is how I call it from outside:
evalPol eps gamma 2 0 gen pol ss [((const 0), 0)] =                  -- Assume delta >= eps and recurse.
evalPol eps gamma 2 1 gen pol ss [(vofs', delta), ((const 0), 0)]

-- Now, expand delta
delta = maximum $ map (abs . uncurry (-) . (vofs &&& vofs')) ss      -- Substitute for vofs, vofs', and pol, using previous iteration's definitions.
      = maximum $ map ( abs
                      . uncurry (-)
                      . ( vofs' &&&
                          \s -> actVal gamma gen vofs' s 0
                        )
                      ) ss
      = maximum $ map ( abs
                      . uncurry (-)
                      . ( \s -> actVal gamma gen (const 0) s 0 &&&
                          \s -> actVal gamma gen (\s' -> actVal gamma gen (const 0) s' 0) s 0
                        )
                      ) ss
```

I see the recursion developing, as expected, but I don't see any nested calling into `evalPol.vofs'`, which might explain the (supposedly) exponential dependency upon `maxIter` that I'm observing.
Furthermore, I've looked at both the `actVal` function, as well as the `gen` function, and there are no calls into `evalPol.vofs'` hiding in either of them.
So, I'm at a loss to explain this very large number of entries into `evalPol.vofs'` that I'm observing in the `maxIter = 2` case.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Without an MCVE, benchmarking this and trying alternatives requires too much effort.

Comment: Yes, shrink your code to the minimal example that still produces this problem. Otherwise, "why isn't this code working?" is an option when voting to close subjects; the general applicability of the Q&A is severely limited when the question gets so specific, and the effort of debugging becomes high.

Comment: `delta = maximum [abs (f s - g s) | s <- ss]` is so much easier to follow. and you didn't include your `gen`, `pol`, and `actVal` definitions.

Comment: I suspect this can be greatly simplified if you don't make it tail-recursive.

Comment: @WillNess, thanks! Yes, I agree, your version is MUCH more readable; I'll make the chang.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for your reply! Could you give me just a little more of a hint, please?

Comment: I'll vote to reopen right now, on the belief that you *will* indeed edit this question as you say you will, :) to *include the relevant and missing* definitions, for [mcve]. Please do this soon.

Comment: Okay, I solved this by using a vector representation of the `vofs'` function. Thanks to all, whom replied. And my apologies to those, whom felt this question was off topic.

Comment: still, you should edit to include all relevant details, then post your own answer and accept it. that's the SO way. these Q&A entries are to serve the community at large, not just the asker. :)

Comment: @dbanas. Instead of building up the result in an accumulator, just prepend the result of the recursive call with the new value: `evalPol ... = (something, delta) : evalPol`. It lets you get rid of some of the parameters to the function.

Comment: You can also get rid of `maxIter` and `nIter` if you just let `evalPol` build an infinite stream of values, then just take the ones you want: `take maxIter (evalPol ...)`.

Comment: @chepner, thank you!

Comment: @WillNess, change to definition of `delta` made, as per your request. I hesitate to start adding more code (i.e. - definitions of `gen`, `pol`, and `actVal`, because they call other functions, which would need to be included, and this question has already been flagged as having code that isn't succinct enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a vector representation of the `vofs'` function.
Doing so has eliminated the redundant calculations that were being performed previously. I now see 882 calls into the new equivalent of `vofs'`, for the *2 recursions* case, which is what I expect. That is, I expect the execution time of `evalPol` to be *linear* in `maxIter` and, using a vector representation of `vofs'`, that's what I'm seeing.